# Should [Multisite] be a Synonym of [Wordpress-mu]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The [multisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multisite) tag has 27 questions and, without the description is not clearly about WordPress.

The [wordpress-mu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-mu) tag has hundreds of questions, and is far more clearly named.

Comment: trying very hard not to answer [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29)

Comment: (1) For some time WordPress MultiUser was a fork, totally incompatible with the base code. Some time after that they integrated it in the base branch renaming it into WordPress MultiSite - but the two versions are not compatible. (https://mu.wordpress.org/) - so no, they are not synonyms. (2) [tag:multisite] sounds way too general a tag to be dedicated to WP-MS only. I don't get why such tag edits ever get approved. There's Ruby, Sitecore and Magento questions tagged with it. Maybe the description should not have been approved?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Given the numbers of questions involved, and that the change to Multi-Site has been around of a while now; is the Multi-Site Muilti-User difference significant enough for tags used over merely a few hundred questions? (And I agree about "Mutltisite" being too generic, but that's hardly unique.)

Comment: I think we should switch [tag:multisite] to [tag:wordpress-mu] in all WP related questions (I counted four that are not). Then we'd get rid of that description on [tag:multisite].

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Looks like you are answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should switch [multisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multisite) to [wordpress-mu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-mu) in all WP related questions.
I counted four ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497636/multisite-environment-using-windows-authentication), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482627/display-all-the-websites-store-configured-in-subdomains-in-magento-website-on-h), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664047/similar-gem-with-multisite-plugin), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673766/enable-use-in-advanced-search-option-of-product-attribute-for-only-one-multi-s)) that are not.

Then we'd get rid of that description on [multisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multisite) to something more general, not tied to WP or, even better, get rid of it until something deserving it appears.